# Using select_related in django for a specific use case?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have these two models and I am trying to build up the logic of given the combination of days ( e.x., Mon-Tue 2-3 pm) I want to find out all the instructor names. I am unable to do that. I have tried using select_related but I am not able to use it properly I think.
:)

```
class TimeSlot(models.Model):
    
    instructor = models.ForeignKey('Instructor', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    day = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=WEEKDAYS)
    start_time = models.TimeField()
    end_time = models.TimeField()
```

```
class Instructor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, validators=[validate_instructor_name])
```

Comment: Share also `WEEKDAYS`. To clarify: `day`: **Mon-Tue**; `start_time`: **2**; `end_time`: **3**?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, filter the `TimeSlot`s and annotate them with instructor names (or just get the timeslots and pull the related instructor names later in your logic)

Untested, off the top of my head:

```
select = TimeSlot.objects.filter(
     day__in = ['Monday', 'Thursday'],       # or whatever
     start_time__gte = start_of_time_window, # f.ex datetime.time( hour=14, minute=30)
     end_time__lte = end_of_time_window,     # f.ex.datetime.time( hour=15)
).select_related( 
     'instructor'
).annotate(
      instructor_name='instructor__name'
)
```

Once you get the annotation working, if you only want the instructor names you can probably do that by adding `.values_list('instructor_name')` (but I'm not sure you can collect annotations in a values list).

`select_related` simply makes sure that the query to the DB also returns related Instructor objects, so a later reference to a filtered `timeslot.instructor.whatever`  doesn't hit the DB again to fetch the instructor object. (This is often referred to as removing the N+1 problem, which IMO should be the 1+N problem)